# How do I open a xaml window from another xaml window using button click?

Tags: xml, xaml, c#

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Win1 OP= new Win1();
            OP.show();
        }
```

OP.show() is throwing an error.

It is a usercontrol form.

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'show'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say that `Win1` is "It is a ***usercontrol*** form." (emphasis is mine).

If `Win1` is actually of type `UserControl`, the issues is that the type `UserControl` doesn't define `Show()` method. So it cannot be "opened" as a window.

To solve this you need to open a window and have the UC as the content for that window:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Win1 OP= new Win1();
    var host = new Window();
    host.Content = OP;
    host.Show();
}
```

As a side note, you can use `UserControl` as `StartupUri` in App.xaml and it will work since the framework recognizes that it's not a window and creates a window for it.

Answer (score 6):

All of these answers are fine, however they do not take advantage of [WPF's Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview) features. If you're going to be hiding/closing the current window anyway, then this is a great alternative to the old `WinForms` window management. Instead of creating multiple windows, create pages and simply display them using a single Frame control in the MainWindow:

```
<Grid>
    <Frame Source="/Menu.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

Then when you want to display another "window" (actually a page), you can use `NavigationService` to change the frame source. From the Menu page code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Contact.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

This will now display the Contact page. Using this method ensures that the window properties are standardized. One window to rule them all!

Comment: Thanks Murmel! I updated the response with some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Opens a window and close the first one :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        window2 win2= new window2();
        win2.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't open UserControl as Window or dialog box. Better add usercontrol into some Window through code behind or XAML and then open that window.
Don't forget to set DataContext of that window. Remember datacontext of parent control/window will get inherited by child controls/usercontrols.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show usercontrol directly, you should render your usercontrol in another window.

like.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();

  var win = new MainWindow();

  win.Content = win1;

  win.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do it like a popup:

```
private void btn1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    newWin win2 = new newWin();
    win2.Show():
}
```